# QGIS issues on Mac OS Big Sur 11.2 GRASS and SCP issue

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, mac, qgis-grass-plugin, scp

I have been having issues with QGIS on my Mac. The current operating system is Big Sur 11.2. The current workaround to the SCP plugin is to revert back to version 6 via these steps: https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2020/10/SCP7.html

However, this method does not consistently work for others with older Mac OS like High Sierra. I am teaching a course and it doesn't always show up. Only version 7 shows up.

Per other recommendations:

I have tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling via Kyngchaos: https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis/

This also includes the older release on the website like 3.10 as well as the newer releases. Each time, I uninstall everything including python and gdal and reinstall from scratch starting with python. The Processing plugin is not turned on and every time I try to activate it, QGIS crashes.

Downloading QGIS from the main website (https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) and trying 3.16 and 3.18, I am able to get SCP 6 working with Big Sur but not with High Sierra.

I can't find older builds beyond 3.8 on QGIS website. They have them for Windows but not Mac OS for some reason.

I was trying to run operations instead in GRASS 7.8.4, but now that is no longer working. I am getting Unicode error and no amount of internet searching has helped me with this. I have no non-ascii characters in my path names that I can find so I am not sure what is going on.

Here is the error message regardless of version. To note, this is the i.pca run but this also happens with older tools like cluster:

```
QGIS version: 3.16.5-Hannover
QGIS code revision: 58ba7c1ed6
Qt version: 5.14.2
GDAL version: 3.2.1
GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'i.pca' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-f' : False, '-n' : False, 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'input' : ['/Users/Rachel/Documents/RS/Lab 7/ipca/band2after.tif','/Users/Rachel/Documents/RS/Lab 7/ipca/band3after.tif','/Users/Rachel/Documents/RS/Lab 7/ipca/band4after.tif','/Users/Rachel/Documents/RS/Lab 7/ipca/band5after.tif','/Users/Rachel/Documents/RS/Lab 7/ipca/band6after.tif','/Users/Rachel/Documents/RS/Lab 7/ipca/band7after.tif'], 'output' : '/Users/Rachel/Documents/RS/Lab 7/ipca', 'percent' : 99, 'rescale' : [0,2550] }

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Algorithm.py", line 423, in processAlgorithm
getattr(self, fullName)(parameters, context, feedback)
File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Algorithm.py", line 499, in processInputs
self.loadRasterLayer(layerName, layer)
File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Algorithm.py", line 746, in loadRasterLayer
self.setSessionProjectionFromLayer(layer)
File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Algorithm.py", line 1044, in setSessionProjectionFromLayer
self.setSessionProjection(layer.crs())
File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Algorithm.py", line 1051, in setSessionProjection
file_name = Grass7Utils.exportCrsWktToFile(crs)
File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Utils.py", line 95, in exportCrsWktToFile
f.write(wkt)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xb0' in position 898: ordinal not in range(128)
Execution failed after 0.11 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'i.pca' finished
_________________________________
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hi, please edit and also add the GRASS GIS version you are using.

Comment: Edited to add GRASS version 7.8.4.

Comment: Do you see a chance to switch to GRASS 7.8.6 dev? You get it at http://grassmac.wikidot.com/downloads - feedback would be welcome since we plan to release 7.8.6 final soon.

Comment: Good to know Markus! I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks!